# Docker container restarting without producing logs

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm encountering an issue with a Docker container where it keeps restarting without producing any logs. Here are the details of my setup:

- I have a Docker Compose configuration with two services: `profiles` and `postgres`.
- The `profiles` service is built from a custom Dockerfile and runs a Python application.
- The `postgres` service uses the official PostgreSQL Docker image.
- Both services are defined in the same `docker-compose.yml` file.
- The profiles service container (`profile-profiles-1`) keeps restarting, but when I try to view its logs using `docker logs profile-profiles-1`, there is no output.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
x-variables: &variables
  ENV_STAGE: local

services:
  profiles:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/dev/web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/usr/src/web/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      <<: *variables
    env_file:
      - compose/dev/env/.env
      - compose/dev/env/.db.env
      - compose/dev/env/.data.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # - compose/dev/db/pg.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
      - ./compose/dev/db/pg.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    # command:
    #   - config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    command: postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf

    env_file:
      - compose/dev/env/.db.env

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

This is my `Dockerfile` for the application:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    HOME=/usr/src/web

WORKDIR $HOME

ARG GID=1000
ARG UID=1000
ARG USER=ubuntu

# install dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache curl postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev openssl libffi-dev openssl-dev build-base \
    # install Pillow dependencies
    jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev harfbuzz-dev fribidi-dev \
    # pygraphviz
    graphviz graphviz-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && addgroup -g $GID -S $USER \
    && adduser -S $USER -G $USER --disabled-password --uid "$UID"

COPY ./web/config/requirements  ./requirements
RUN pip install -r ./requirements/local.txt

COPY --chown=$USER:$USER . /
COPY --chown=$USER:$USER ./web $HOME

RUN chmod +x /*.sh \
    && mkdir -p $HOME/static /redis_socket \
    && chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/static \
    && chmod -R 777 /redis_socket \
    && flake8 .

USER $USER
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Checked the Dockerfile and Docker Compose configuration for the profiles service to ensure it's correctly configured.
- Verified that the application code inside the profiles service container is set up to write logs to stdout or stderr.
- Ensured that the container health checks are not failing immediately upon startup.

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to determine why the container is not producing any logs or why it keeps restarting.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue? Are there any additional steps I can take to diagnose the problem or gather more information about why the container is restarting?

Thank you in advance for your help!